# Why does the output image appear at 772 x 772 px even though I design it as 256 x 256 px?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created an icon in Adobe Illustration at 256 x 256 pixels.

When I output the file, it is shown as 772 x 772 pixels.

What is happening here, and how do I solve it?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: _how_ exactly are you outputting the file?

Comment: How... is this a programming question?

Comment: Actually no.  But it is still active (i.e., approved as a programming question) for almost 1 month.  So, let it be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. New Document.  Units = Pixels.  Width = 256 px.  Height = 256 px.
2. Align your artwork inside the given boundaries.
3. Export as PNG (as shown on your 2nd screenshot).